# Programmatically Apply SublimeText Key

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sublimetext2

I'm trying to completely automate setting up a new Ubuntu instance and am wondering if anybody knows how to programmatically apply your license key from a bash script. Any takers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to copy `License.sublime_license` file (which contains your license key) to `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Settings/`.

Answer (score 0):

For SublimeText 3 (at least) the following applies:

- The path is now `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/License.sublime_license`
- On a fresh install, the folder `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/` would require creation beforehand.
- The `License.sublime_license` needs to have, as a payload, the plaintext variant for it to be processed on sublime startup.

Comment: How do you mean payload? Is `License.sublime_license` a plaintext file?

Comment: Programatically doing it, you would have to add it as a plaintext file, then on sublime start-up you will see it change and the license would be applied.